# Storage needed for exploratory Vue.js examples

Tags: vue.js

Just confirming a basic fact.

To run an [introductory example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

```
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})
```

the storage needed on my hard disk is of the order of 175MB.

Am I missing something, or is this the way it is with Vue.js v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing with 175MB you mean a [CLI and NPM based development environment](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI).

Well, no, in order to run that introductory example **you don't necessarily need such environment**.

You can follow the [`<script>`-based development environment](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include), which will take **little to none space**, because Vue will be loaded from a CDN.

That said, you could hit the **limitations** soon after "deepening", like when starting with [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). Also the big part of QA and tutorials assume CLI env.

---

*Keep in mind that this is the workflow with any modern JavaScript framework's dev environment. That taken space is there for a reason, and it is to help you build your app, for example with Vue's CLI you get "hot-reload, lint-on-save, and production-ready builds" and more. Also you can add NPM packages and import them into your project*

Comment: That’s much better already. The need for 175MB to get "hot reload, etc" doesn't bother me. But the need to duplicate this storage 100 times for 100 independent introductory examples does. A modern framework should enable me to share most of the 175MB among different 100 examples (by pointing to the common part), and incur additional storage when customizing.